# symfony - log custom propel query

Tags: symfony1, propel

we using symfony 1.0. We have an module work with Propel objects. The sql-querys are visible in the symfony-debugbar under the "DB" menu.

My problem is that we also use custom sql-querys via propel::getRS("select ...")
This querys are not visible in the debug bar.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommended way**

The standard logger in symfony would be the recommended method:

from inside an action:

```
$this->logMessage('executed SQL: '.$sql);
```

from inside the model (or anywhere else):

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getLogger()->info('executed SQL: '.$sql);
```

These methods would insert your SQL queries into the 'logs & msgs' tab in the debug toolbar in the correct position in the execution chain.

***However***, if you just want to see the queries at the *top* of the 'logs & msgs' tab and don't need them to be stored in the permanent log, you can use `$this->debugMessage($sql);` instead, which would also mean you could see the queries together, and not search for them through the log execution chain.

**A potentially preferable way**

I suspect that you may want these SQL queries to appear on the 'DB' tab instead. This isn't directly supported by symfony, but you could 'hack' this solution instead:

from inside an action:

```
$this->logMessage(sprintf("{sfCreole} executeQuery(): [x.xx ms] %s", $sql));
```

from inside the model:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getLogger()->info(sprintf("{sfCreole} executeQuery(): [x.xx ms] %s", $sql));
```

This mimics the behaviour of the debug option in symfony for logging SQL queries, and will therefore push your custom SQL query into the 'DB' tab in the debug toolbar. I leave the timing [x.xx ms] option up to you to implement if you wish it :)